# Is there any method to unblock the website from Facebook?

Tags: facebook, social-media

I am handling a domain `www.example.com`
after putting this URL in Facebook, it says the domain looks suspicious.

1. It is a eCommerce website, no issues found by whois
2. Webmaster is set but, it seems fine to the site(no malware attack)
3. Already written to Facebook about clarifying domain issue, but no reply.

Is there any method to unblock the website from Facebook?

Answer (score 5):

Here is [the official Facebook form for appealing a website block](https://www.facebook.com/help/contact/244560538958131).

The form asks you to explain why the block is an error.

[image]

---

The help forums on Facebook are full of threads ([1](https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=10151617465671272), [2](https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=10151472724566829), [3](https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=10200364349931159), [4](https://help.instagram.com/help/community/question/?id=10100963872359031)) from owners of websites that have been blocked and are asking to be unblocked.    There don't appear to be a lot of options when your site is blocked other than appealing and complaining in the forums.  I would not expect complaining to be effective if your appeal did not work.

Comment: I did this before, but there is no responce from fb. Is there any other way?

Comment: I added additional info to the answer.